# Reusable Included Layouts

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

I've just discovered that you can include an .axml layout file inside of another by using the  tag. This is great, allowing encapsulation of some common layout themes, however what I'm now wondering is whether there is a way to bind some code/logic to the included layout?

My include layout contains a few buttons, and I'd like each of these buttons to take the user to a different Activity. Obviously, I don't want to have to repeat the code inside of each Activity so is there a way I can write a class that contains the logic for the included layout and bind it?

If anyone could provide an example that would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse a method that you have written for a certain button but there will be some boiler plate code that comes with it.
You can either:

1. In each activity add your method to the buttons `Click` event.

OR

2. Define a click method in the XML and then implement it in your activities (with a base class or individually) like so:

---

### The activity

```
[Java.Interop.Export("SomeButtonClick")]
public void SomeButtonClick(View v)
{
    YourReusableMethod();
}
```

### The axml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/some_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="SomeButtonClick" />
```

Comment: So would you declare YourResuableMethod() in a generic library class?

Comment: It depends on your architecture, but it will work as long as it is accessible (public, internal)